# How I can prevent autofilling with autocomplete="off" in angular material input field

Tags: angular, input, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

My code is:

```html
 <input matInput formControlName="addressLine2" (blur)="onBlurSetValue()" name="addressLine2" autocomplete="doNotAutoComplete" />
```

I have also tried using `autocomplete="off"`.

Both are not working for me.

My expectation is I want to remove the auto suggestion that comes for address line field 1.

Comment: what you have should work. interesting. did try to add autocomplete on the form tag?